# Y-Combinator factorial in javascript works for numbers not for the Church numerals.

Tags: javascript, lambda-calculus, y-combinator, church-encoding

I managed to implement Church encoding and Y-Combinator using ES6 arrow function in javascript. But when I tried to evaluate the factorial function,

```
FALSE = a => b => b 
TRUE = a => b => a 

ZERO = f => z => z
ONE = f => z => f(z)
SIX = f => z => f(f(f(f(f(f(z))))))
isZERO = n => n(x => FALSE)(TRUE)
SUCC = n => f => z => f(n(f)(z))
MULT = n => m => f => z => n(m(f))(z)

PAIR = a => b => z => z(a)(b)
FIRST = p => p(a => b => a)
SECOND = p => p(a => b => b)
ZZ = PAIR(ZERO)(ZERO)
SS = p => PAIR(SECOND(p))(SUCC(SECOND(p)))
PRED = n => FIRST(n(SS)(ZZ))

FactGen = fact => n =>
  isZERO(n)
    (ONE)
    (MULT(n)(fact(PRED(n))))

Y = g => (x => g(y => x(x)(y))) (x => g(y => x(x)(y)))

Y(FactGen)(SIX) (x=>x+1)(0)
```

I got 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)' error.

If I change FactGen,

```
FactGen = fact => n => n == 0 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1)
Y(FactGen)(6)
720
```

It just works.

What I want to know is Church numeral version of it.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that JavaScript is not lazy evaluated. Specifically, the `isZero` "if" does evaluate all of its arguments before it can check whether the first is zero.

We can fix that using an `if` with unit functions:

```
// type Bool = a -> a -> a
// type Lazy a = () -> a
// IF :: Bool -> Lazy a -> Lazy a -> a
IF = c => a => b => c(a)(b)()

FactGen = fact => n =>
  IF(isZERO(n))
    (()=>ONE)
    (()=>MULT(n)(fact(PRED(n))))
//   ^^^^
```

or omit the `IF` wrapper and change your boolean encodings directly to

```
// type Bool = Lazy a -> Lazy a -> a
FALSE = a => b => b()
TRUE = a => b => a()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Bergi.

    FactGen = fact => n =>
      isZERO(n)
        (() => ONE)
        (() => MULT(n)(fact(PRED(n))))

It worked!